# "Option does not exist" with bash case statement

Tags: bash, case, flags

I'm trying to do the following to add a simple switch to a bash command. The flag is for turning on an option to do some file backup tasks with another program called 'terminus'.

However, when I run my script (named `prepmultidev.sh`) like this:

```sh
bash prepmultidev.sh mysite.updatejan31 -b
```

When I add the `-b` option at the end of the command, it says "Skipping backup" (even though it's supposed to say "Backing up live/test/dev...") and then I'm getting an error saying "The '-b' option does not exist". And when I don't add it, it still says "Skipping backup" (correctly now) but returns with "Not enough arguments (missing: 'multidev')." After reading tutorial upon tutorial, I'm using the same code as others who got it working, but mine isn't and I'm still just as confused as when I started.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Example: bash prepmultidev.sh mysite multidevname
# will back up live/test/dev and create a multidev of mysite.
# Add the -b flag if a backup of live/test/dev is required.
SITE=$1
MULTIDEV=$2
BACKUP=$3

# Exit on error
set -e

# Authenticate Terminus
terminus auth:login --machine-token=J6nCtWYtva8dtPk3xQ95ZJIG6FuSfQ6t14c0to-tmhH9R

# Check to see if a backup is needed of live/test/dev.

    case "$BACKUP" in
        b)
            echo "Backing up live/test/dev..."
            # Create backups of live, test, and dev environments
            terminus backup:create $SITE.live & 
            terminus backup:create $SITE.test &
            terminus backup:create $SITE.dev &
            ;;
        *) 
            echo "Skipping backup"
            ;;
    esac

# Now do some other stuff with $SITE.$MULTIDEV
```

What am I missing to make this recognize the `-b` flag when it's present and do the backups, or to simply echo "Skipping backup" when it's not?

Comment: Did you run this with `set -x` to see what values  are being used for variables? Also, `-b !- b`. . Good luck.

Comment: Adding ```set -x```. it outputs this:

```+ case "$BACKUP" in
+ echo 'Skipping backup'
Skipping backup
+ terminus multidev:create webidextrous.upd01312021.live -b```

Comment: As pointed out, `-b` is not the same as `b`.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was missing, was the ```-b``` vs. just ```b```. I also was inadvertently putting a ```.``` between the first two arguments of $SITE and $MULTIDEV when running the script. They needed a space between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bash `case` statement requires you to specify a pattern, but if you do not specify any of the [pattern matching syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching), it will only match a whole string. In your example, `b)` will match `b`, but not `-b`.

To resolve your immediate issue, you can specify the `-` in your case pattern as well to make it match:

```sh
    case "$BACKUP" in
        -b)
            echo "Backing up live/test/dev..."
            # Create backups of live, test, and dev environments
            terminus backup:create $SITE.live & 
            terminus backup:create $SITE.test &
            terminus backup:create $SITE.dev &
            ;;
        *) 
            echo "Skipping backup"
            ;;
    esac
```

If you wish to add more flags though, you might fare better using [`getopts`](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) or the more flexible [`GNU getopt`](https://linuxaria.com/howto/parse-options-in-your-bash-script-with-getopt) if you have it available to you (not to be confused with BSD or POSIX `getopt`, which is more limited).